# Java 8 Convert Object to String separated by VALUE

Tags: java, object, java-8

I'm trying to conver a java Object to a string separated by "SEPARATOR".

Example

```
public class Person{

int id;
String name;
String age;
String sex;
}
```

Main method

```
Person per = new Person(1, "Kevin", "20", "Male");
String objectAsText = per.ConvertObjectToString(per, "|");
```

Expected output

```
1|Kevin|20|Male
```

Note that the java object **is not** a list. And I also want to add a validation so the method `ConvertObjectToString` can avoid printing object values that are null. ie

```
Person per = new Person(1, "Kevin", "Male");
String objectAsText = per.ConvertObjectToString(per, "|");
```

Expected output

```
1|Kevin|Male
```

I know that this can be achieved using toString method, but I want to know if there is any other efficient way. Also I don't want to check value by value if null since the java object can be large.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As mentioned in the question I override the toString method and had concatenated my values. But I think it is not the perfect solution.

Comment: There is _not_ likely to be a better solution.

Comment: Why override `toString()`?  Just make the `ConvertObjectToString` method do what you want. BTW: if `ConvertObjectToString` is a member method of `Person`, it shouldn't take the `Person` as an argument.

Comment: Are you trying to create the strings generically, without hard-coding the specific fields? So the `ConvertObjectToString` method would automatically adapt if more fields were added later? If so, edit your your Question to say so. Your Question is not clear as presently written.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to check each value, I would recommend java object converting into JSON, like into `Map<String,Object>` and then use [Collectors.joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
String value = map.values()
            .stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

You can do it using the reflection package, but make sure your fields are `public`

```
 Person per = new Person(1, "Kevin", "20", "Male");

   String value = Arrays.stream(Person.getClass().getFields())
           .map(f-> {
               try {
                   return f.get(per).toString();
               } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               return null;
           }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));

    System.out.println(value); //1|Kevin|20|Male
```